# Different routing result with Javascript calculateRoute vs iOS calculateRoute

Tags: here-api

There is a difference between the result of the Javascript API 'calculateRoute' function call from H.service.Platform.getRoutingService(null,8) (Javascript API version 3.1)
And the result of the iOS SDK 'calculateRoute' function from NMACoreRouter. (Premium sdk v 3.1.9)

If I pass in the options
routingType: fastest
transportMode: truck

And I pass in exactly the same set of waypoints.
E.g.
Stopover: -34.909797,138.5403
via: -34.85191,138.49499
via: -34.851,138.49494
via: -34.84965,138.49478
via: -34.84868,138.4947
via: -34.84765,138.49459
via: -34.84681,138.49448
via: -34.84654,138.49439
via: -34.84556,138.49392
via: -34.84252,138.49306
via: -34.84131,138.49272
Stopover: -34.827869,138.500708

Then the via waypoint that is on a bridge will make the javascript route drive down side roads to pass over the bridge. However the iOS API will continue to drive under the bridge.

Is there a way to make the two engines calculate identically?

Javascript:
[image: Javascript Here Route Result]

iOS:
[image: iOS CoreRouter calculate route]

Answer (score 1):

Both engines uses different routing APIs. So it is not possible to get identical results. The Premium sdk v 3.1.9 works on Routing V7 ,whereas the the javascripts works on routing v8.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/index.html

Comment: Just to confirm, Does the Navigate edition use the v8 routing engine?

Comment: Why does Routing v8 introduce errors in the route when an intermediate point is at the location of a bridge, when v7 had no such problems? Version 8 is worse.